# How to link semantic UI drop down list using JQUERY?

Tags: jquery, html, semantic-ui

My code is

```
<div class="ui teal inverted menu">
<a class="active item">
<i class="home icon"></i>Home
</a>

<div class="ui dropdown item">
Stock<i class="dropdown icon"></i>
<div class="menu">
<div class="item">Real Time Monitoring</div>
<div class="item" >Market Summary</div>
</div>
</div>
```

How to map to jquery? Can anyone please answer?

Comment: Semantic UI dropdown markup is there, where is the code you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this as sample [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/8z6s2m7a/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/8z6s2m7a/)

```
<div class="ui teal inverted menu">
<a class="active item">
<i class="home icon"></i>Home
</a>

<div class="ui dropdown item" id="divDDL">
Stock<i class="dropdown icon"></i>
<div class="menu">
<div class="item">Real Time Monitoring</div>
<div class="item" >Market Summary</div>
</div>
</div>

$("#divDDL").dropdown();
```

Comment: Both are not working, I tried giving ID bt still it's not displaying the sub lists

Comment: have you check jsfiddle in my answer?

Comment: very sorry , I got it Thank you so much @Bharatsing Parmar

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your dropdown like so:

```
$('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown()
;
```

Please found more information in this [HERE](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html)